# How can I update a default value for a form field after an ajax submission (not a form reset)

Tags: php, jquery, html, event-handling

I am using jQuery to submit my form via AJAX. This updates a database record and then returns a response for success or failure. The issue I am having is not critical but more for convenience.

When resetting a form it resets all the fields to their default values from when the page loads (for sake of simplicity.) This is not the behavior I want. The reason I want to change this is because if I submit the form and I then decide to change the value again then I decide I want to reset the form back to my last submitted values, it resets back to the initial defaults and not my new values that were recently submitted and saved in the database.

To try and better explain this I will show my process with the form field for a user's username.

```
Username: SomeDefaultUserNameFetched
```

I then change the username to Foo.

```
Username: Foo
```

I submit the form via AJAX and get a success response.
I then decide maybe I don't like Foo and would prefer Bar.

```
Username: Bar
```

Then I decide I don't like Bar and Foo was just fine so I decide to reset the form.
Resetting the form will give me:

```
Username: SomeDefaultUserNameFetched
```

As you can see the form reset is not saving my recently submitted form data. So my question is how can I, if this is even possible, update the form defaults so that when I hit reset the form will reset the fields with my latest submission.

Thanks and I really hope someone can push me in the right direction or let me know if this is even possible.

**UPDATE:**
I would like to be able save this into the DOM if possible. Where are the default values stored at in the first place? I know I could modify my custom form reset to handle setting the form element values but I was trying not to have to cause this overhead if there was a way to update the DOM.

Thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found Solution:**
I found this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp as my solution. By looping through my submission content I can update the default values as they are changed.

Answer (score 1):

there are three ways I can think of to do this:

1) send a new ajax request and fetch data from the database so that you will have the latest data being show upon form reset.

2) keep a JSON object (e.g. form_state) which will keep track of the latest valid state of the form

3) keep the defaults in some hidden fields (or even as attributes) and reset the form from there

Answer (score 0):

Create an attribute called default:

```
<input type="text" default="Some Name" id="name" />
```

When you want to update default just use something like this:

```
$("#name").attr("default","Ivan Castellanos")
```

And the reset button would be super simple:

```
$("#reset_btn").click(function(){
    $("[default]").val(function(){return $(this).attr("default")})
})
```

Good luck.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I could also easily store the new values in an array in JS and update my form reset to set all the value in a simple loop. The approach I was looking for was to be able to update this into the DOM. I assume there has to be some way to update the data since it is saved somewhere... My search continues. I appreciate the suggestion though.

Comment: The default values are stored in the browser and you don't have access to them.

Comment: Actually, they are stored in the defaultValue property of each input, but is not actually in the DOM

Comment: I was able to find this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_defaultvalue.asp seems to work how I want. Thanks for you assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<input type="reset">` button to be a plain button and then add your own click event handler. Within your ajax submit save the values that were submitted, and within the button click handler change back to the saved values:

```
<input type="button" id="resetForm" value="Reset">

<script>
$("#resetForm").click(function() {
   // restore previously saved form values here
});
</script>
```

As for exactly how to save the values, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader... (Hint: I'd either use an object or add data attributes to each form element.)

Comment: This is more easily accomplished with using:

    $(":reset").bind('click', function (event) {
    });

I'm looking for another method but it may not exist. Thanks