# form_for reset button not updating values after AJAX response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, reset

I'm trying to use the form_for reset button:

```
<%= button_tag 'Reset', :type => 'reset' %>
```

It works great, but when I update the object through AJAX, how can I get the new form values to be the ones reset to? Right now it resets to the values when the document loads, which makes sense. But is there a way to get the reset button to register the new values?

Here's the code:
https://gist.github.com/3006966

Hopefully, there's a simpler way than looping through the form fields and setting their default values:
[How can I update a default value for a form field after an ajax submission (not a form reset)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767048/how-can-i-update-a-default-value-for-a-form-field-after-an-ajax-submission-not)

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Rails helper just adds a 'type=reset' attribute to the input tag.  And the rest of the magic is straight from regular HTML.

I ended up doing something like this:

```
$(this)[0].defaultValue = $(this).val();
```

Hope this helps somebody.